# Are browser extensions that allow css :visited to start working again a security breach?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

All browsers have restricted `:visited` for better security. [(Mozilla's page for details.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)

This is quite troublesome when visiting a lot of pages.

I have been using the extension 'stylus' which targets all pages that start with an http to do this:

```
:visited {color:palevioletred !important;}
```

This used to work well 5 yrs back. This is because browser vendors had left a few properties like color usable (detailed in Mozilla's page), so the above code worked. But I have found that more and more pages are unaffected by the above code (as of 2020).

Fortunately there are [lots of browser extensions that allow :visited to start working again](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=visited&type=extension), and they work reliably.

BUT

**Do these extensions make the browser vulnerable again?

Or are they using some other way to make the visited links colored differently?**

*Can someone check the code in these extensions to see what they are doing?*

Comment: We are not code review site

Comment: **It was actually removed by the author of the answer.**  Please be respectful of all users even those users you disagree with.  Even if I was responsible for removing the answer, by voting to delete the answer, it would have taken additional community votes in order to happen.  **I am not a Super User moderator.**  The author indicated the reason, within an edit to their now deleted answer, "This answer was written [for an older version of the question](https://superuser.com/revisions/1563466/1)."

Comment: Could you please tell me the right procedure to solve a question like the above? I had assumed that lots of people who are familiar with the internal of Firefox would know the answer already. Asking to check the code was just an extra option. Importantly, I would love to know why the author of the answer had deleted it, as it was a well though out detailed answer, and I am thankful to him.

Comment: The author based on the comment within the answer, their answer no longer applied to your question, due to the changes you made to your question.  I have no other explanation of why the author would have deleted their answer.